# Is there any simpler way to convert a tensor to java array in java tf-api?

Tags: java, tensorflow

I start to learn how to use maven artifact to run tensorflow in java recently.

At the beginning, I use v1.15.0 version, it's very easy to change a tensor to float array by just using `tensor.copyTo(float[][])`

However, in the new version of tf2 (artifact version 0.3.1) some APIs are changed, such as the tensor.copyTo(). In this version, the formal parameter changed to NdArray instead of float[][] or something else and some other class are introduced such as FloatNdArray, FloatDataBuffer. It confused me a lot.

Since my old style code no longer works, I try to reconstruct it like below:

```java
    try (TFloat32 out = (TFloat32) runner.run().get(0)) {
            FloatNdArray matrix = StdArrays.ndCopyOf(new float[1][1]);
            out.copyTo(matrix);
            FloatDataBuffer floatDataBuffer = DataBuffers.ofFloats(1);
            matrix.read(floatDataBuffer);
            float[] res = new float[1];
            floatDataBuffer.read(res);
        }
```

This code looks really ugly.

I have to instantialize a FloatDataBuffer and a FloatNdArray just as intermediaries.

Is there any pretty way to do this conversion?

Comment: I'm no expert on tensorflow but having a look at the API it looks like `TFloat32` extends `NdArray <Float>` and has a static method `tensorOf(NdArray <Float>)`. Did you try `TFloat32.tensorOf(out)`?

Comment: @Thomas You remind me that it is purely abundant to use anothor FloatNdArray to receive value from parameter 'out', I didn't notice that TFLoat32 exntends FloatNdArray already, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I find the solution with the help of @Thomas.

Since the `TFloat32` has already extended `FloatNdArray`, it is totally unnecessary to create another `FloatNdArray` to pass the value.

What's more, I find a series of methods named after `arrayXdCopyOf` in `StdArrays.class`,

It can copy values from `NdArray` to Java primitive type array directly.
The X value is just the number of dimensions of `NdArray`.

My code can be simplified as below:

```
try (TFloat32 out = (TFloat32) runner.run().get(0)) {
    float[][] res = StdArrays.array2dCopyOf(out);
}
```